# Google sheets custom scripts is running twice, once correctly and the second time incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm writing a simple function to take in two parameters in google sheets. First parameter is the 'value' which is the amount of money is being negotiated with a cliente. The second parameter is the 'percentage' or likely hood they will close a deal. What i want the function to do is to analyze if the likely hood of the deal is over 50% and if so add the amount of that deal to the total.

The point is that I can have a clear idea of the total amount that can be earned based on deals that have a likely hood of over 50% of closing.

```
function realisticBusiness(...data) {
  let total = 0;

  data.map(([value, percentage]) => {
    if(percentage > 0.50) total = total + value
    return value;
  });
  

  return console.log(total);
}

realisticBusiness([600, 0.50], [600, 60], [500, 0.65])
```

In this scenario the values of the second and third arrays of 600 and 500 should be added because the percentage is over 0.50, and should get a return value of 1100.

But what I get instead in the console.log is that the code is running twice and in the first run it gives the value correctly of 1100, and in the second run it comes back as 0. (the image is in portuguese but I think you get the ideia)

[I can't yet embed pictures to my post but the link bellow in the console log that i get in return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFgxn.png)

Comment: In your script, if you run `realisticBusiness` with the script editor, the following flow is run. 1. As the global, `realisticBusiness([600, 0.50], [600, 60], [500, 0.65])` is run. 2. Function `realisticBusiness(...data)` is run with no arguments. By this, The results of `1100` and `0` are shown. This is the reason for your current issue. If you want to show only one result, how about modifying `realisticBusiness([600, 0.50], [600, 60], [500, 0.65])` to `const sample = _ => realisticBusiness([600, 0.50], [600, 60], [500, 0.65]);`, and run `sample`? By this, only one result is shown in the log.